# How to burn Ubuntu Desktop v12.04.3-i386.iso file to a CD or a DVD disc?

Tags: iso

The Ubuntu ISO file I downloaded wants to burn exclusively to a CD disc, but the files in the ISO file are too large to fit to any 700MB CD disc I currently have available.

It won't accept a DVD as the destination media.

Are there any files that I can delete from the ISO file?

Alternatively, will extracting the files from the ISO file and creating another bootable ISO file acceptable to a DVD disc be a workable solution, or is there something I'm missing in this endeavor?

thx

Ted

Answer (score 0):

use **Brasero**  , click burn image , dvd should be ok .  or you could use USB stick to install OS.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows OS, try PowerISO. You can do it using a trial version. Else use YUMI,
which you can download using [this link.](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/)

Answer (score 0):

Download Ubuntu mini iso and burn it to the 700 mb cd.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not to change any file in the ISO file if you don't prefer to get any problem soon or late instead I would definitely suggest to burn the file on a USB stick,

if you are in Windows:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

if you are in Ubuntu:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu